# str_replace is not woking with input

Tags: php, string

To remove the new line the following code is working good;

```
<?php 
  $text = "Hello \nwelcome to \ngeeksforgeeks"; 
  $text = str_replace("\n", "", $text); 
 echo $text; 
?>
```

OUTPUT:Hello welcome to geeksforgeeks.

But when i get it as input it is not working;

```
 <form method="post">
       <label>enter string</label>&nbsp
       <input type="text" name="string"></input><br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="enter"></input>
 </form>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['enter']))
    {
      $text=$_POST['string'];
     $out=str_replace("\n","",$text);
      echo $out;

     }
 ?>
```

INPUT:Hello \nwelcome to \ngeeksforgeeks;

OUTPUT:Hello \nwelcome to \ngeeksforgeeks.

please tell me the reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a double-quoted string, `\n` is an escape sequence that becomes a newline character. You want to match literal `\n` in the user input, so you should use a single-quoted string, which doesn't process escape sequences.

```
if(isset($_POST['enter']))
{
    $text=$_POST['string'];
    $out=str_replace('\n',"",$text);
    echo $out;
}
```

See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Or you can escape the escape with an extra '\'
str_replace("\\n","",$text);

Answer (score 0):

$out=str_replace('\n',"",$text);
 or 
$out=str_replace("\\n","",$text);